# Android determine memory leak in program

Tags: android, memory, memory-leaks, mat

OK so I have been at this for days and I still can make sense of the MAT program for eclipse.
I can tell I have a memory leak because when running my application I only have about 2% free memory. here is an image from mat https://i.stack.imgur.com/amkuL.png showing the memory leak. if you want to download the dump I posted it here http://www.mediafire.com/?y1ve41ti1ai5dti Any help one this would be great.

Some background on the application: the main screen has several buttons taking you to new activities. The second button brings you to the games start screen. From here pressing start calls penguin activity which creates a new gameview class which will load the bitmaps into a hashmap and use throughout the game to paint on the canvas.

Comment: Hey, I hope you figured this out. If so, please help me to understand how to translate information in MAT? I saw your screenshot, I have exactly the same problem suspect 1. I would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the "dominator tree" button in order to understand where the issues lie. It open the dominator tree for the entire heap. It will allows you to identify easily the biggest retained chunks of memory.